# strtok() does not function properly

Tags: c, strtok

When I try to separete token this "(555) 333-444", below code is not giving the desired output. I need function to separate all these 555, 333, 444 separately.
What can be my mistake?

Output:

555

333-444

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

char *ptr;

char tel[]="(555) 333-444";

ptr=strtok(tel,"-() ");

while (ptr!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    ptr=strtok(NULL," ");

}

getch();
}
```

Comment: False, `strtok()` does function properly. It is your code that doesn't.

Comment: I forgot to add brackets and - in second call. My mistake. Sorry

Comment: btw, now is a good time to delete the question, and get your six points back ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight why not? he still has one bracket ')' after first strtok call.

Comment: @zubergu `strtok` consumes the opening `(`, produces the `555` output, and puts `\0` in place of the closing `)`. It starts the next round of parsing at the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
ptr=strtok(NULL," ");
```

Should actually be:

```
ptr=strtok(NULL,"-() ");
```

You need to always indicate the delimiters you're going to use in the loop. `strtok` won't "remember" them.

Or you could have something like `const char* delimiters = "-() ";` and just use that every time you use `strtok` with that set of delimiters (e.g. `ptr = strtok(string, delimiters);`).

You won't have to manually list all the delimiters you need.